# My String is not being read but, my integer's are

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having issues with my code here. When I run it. I type in discord the word Resource, and if working properly; my bot would say: Resource Capacity. But it does not do it. If I send a integer such as 2 or 3... it works just fine as i would expect it to. As far as the "Resource", I cannot understand why it does not send the content back. Any ideas on why?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):


    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")

    if message.content.lower() == "Resource":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content = "Resource Capacity")
    elif "2" in message.content.lower():
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content = "Gold")
    elif "3" in message.content.lower():
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content = "test")
```

Comment: message.content.lower() == "Resource" always false isn't it?

Comment: Thanks to Marcus, it was because i was calling it a uppercase and not a lower case!

Comment: @TedWPatterson if my answer solved your problem, please accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `.lower()` method, which converts a string to lowercase.

`'Resource'` has an uppercase letter.

Comment: So would Ted need to use some string concatenation for "R", if he needs to match "Resource"?

Comment: @monkSinha If it were me, I would either match the lowercase string or `'Resource'` exactly, without applying any further formatting.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks, @Marcus !